# Prometheus - Exporter Describe Interface

Tags: prometheus

I'm implementing my own exporter which uses the Prometheus Exporter Interfaces - `Describe` and `Collect`.

I am creating metrics on the fly during the execution of the `Collect` function with `MustNewConstMetric`, and I will also create their descriptors at that point. Therefore they won't necessarily be available for the `Describe` function.

What is the purpose of the `Describe` interface, and how/when is it used?

Answer (score 0):

Currently `Describe` isn't used for much. It's not required to provide all your descriptors in advance, but you should provide what you can.